# about c# code string and int

Tags: c#

I want that c# prints word like "internet" like this:

```
internet
 internet
  internet
   internet
    internet
     internet
      internet
       internet
```

This is my code:

```
string word = ("internet");

for (int i = 0; i < word.Length ; i++) 
{
  Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

With my code i get like that

```
internet
internet
internet
internet
internet
internet
internet
internet
```

Comment: Yes, looks like the correct output for the code you posted. What is your question?

Comment: @Oded , I couldn't stop laughing.... +1

Comment: Of course, it makes lough. But it also doesn't show any research effort. -1

Comment: Seems like a school homework. Homework/exercise is about you learning stuff not asking others to do it for you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
        string word = "internet";

        for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(new string(' ', i));
            Console.WriteLine(word);
        }
```

Comment: @KooKiz:can u please explain what new string(' ', i) does??will it create space i number of times

Comment: @karthi Exactly. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w.aspx

Comment: I'm amazed accepted solution doesn't use `PadLeft` method that would consolidate two method calls...

Answer (score 2):

The code should be:

```
string word = ("internet");

for (int i = 0; i < word.Length ; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < i ; j++) 
    {
        Console.Write(" ");
    }

    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well have you tried:

```
  string word = ("internet");
  int count = word.length;

  for (int i = 0; i < count ; i++) 
  {
    Console.WriteLine(word);
    word =""+word;
  }
```

?

Comment: this is no good idea, if you add " " to word the for loop will never end

Comment: +1 ah - true - must engage brain before keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below; it will work:

```
string word = ("internet");
string displayword = ("internet");

for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(displayword);
    displayword = " " + displayword;
}
```

Comment: This is really not neat.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter solution than proposed so far using [`string.PadLeft()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk6ydzx.aspx) to pad the word with leading space characters:

```
string word = "internet";
for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(word.PadLeft(word.Length + i));
```